# Arduino Mega 2560

Tags: arduino

[image][image]

I am trying to build an aquarium controller using the arduino mega 2560. I found a schematic online to follow but i have a few questions about it. Like what is the the device all the way to the left, it looks like a bread board, it says that it needs to be connected to Arduino D10 and D11 does anyone know where that is. Also how many amps is the power supply? If anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Please post a schematic. Diagrams like these make my thinker box hurt.

Comment: I just added a picture of the schematic.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this device?

Answer (score 1):

This diagram really does not have all the needed information...

The device all the way to the left is a picture of what the bread board circuit could look like on perf board. It is the same two P-FETs and a 5V regulator?

D10 and D11 appear to be the two pins driving the FET gates, basically they turn the motors on and off, most likely also control them via PWM?

The power supply needs to be at-least 12V based on the schematic. But the current requirement will be determined by the motors.

Comment: i just added a picture of the schematic, maybe that will help.